# Return a simeple true or false to conditions - Ubercart Conditional Actions

Tags: php, action, conditional-statements, ubercart

I'm trying to set up a conditional action for shipping quotes in Ubercart.  I need check the hour of day as a condition.  I'm using the execute custom PHP condition.  If the php returns true I just want the predicate to continue onto the actions.  If it returns false I want it to stop.  I tried:

```
    if (date('G') >14 && date('G') < 18){
       return true;
    }
    else{
       return false;
    }
```

When I tried this the shipping estimator just never delivered a quote.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that `date('G')` indeed returns a number between 15 and 17 inclusive?

Comment: I did, thank you.  I manually set my timezone in php.ini .  I ran a php file with just this code that would return some text to indicate that it was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct. Problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: You were right.  The problem was in some of the other fine tunings.  Once I knew that returning true or false was the proper method, it was easy to track down the real source.  Thank you very much.  I will say, it is strange that I could not find this documentation anywhere else.  I hope others find this helpful.